# Different character encoding per browser for Apache SSI

Tags: php, apache, drupal, character-encoding, ssi

First I'd like to preface with the following:

- I realize using mixed character encoding on a site is probably not the best idea, but this configuration has been working fine for years.
- This issue does not seem to affect Chrome (33.0.1750.154), but it does IE (11) and Firefox (24.0 and 28.0).
- In both IE and Firefox, the content will appear fine on the first load, but will experience the issue on subsequent loads (even after clearing cache and restarting the browser). Occasionally I will witness a successful load randomly a while after my previous attempt.
- To the best of my knowledge, nothing relevant on the server has changed.

Most of our site is served as ISO-8859-1, with some pages using UTF-8. Some of the ISO-8859-1 pages need to include PHP-generated UTF-8 content via Apache SSI. When this is the case, the PHP script uses the iconv() function to convert UTF-8 to CP1252 (I believe I'm using this instead for those pesky Windows characters). As noted above this set up has been working fine for years.

Today I learned that this included content was appearing oddly and I confirmed the issue in Firefox and IE. But as I mentioned, it loads fine in Chrome, and often fine in the other browsers -- but only on the first load.

Here is sample page (see right column): http://www.pccnaturalmarkets.com/producers/index.html

Which includes via Apache SSI: http://www.pccnaturalmarkets.com/pcc/videos/_recent/producer/all

The first link should load a bulleted list of video images and linked titles, which is does in Chrome. But in Firefox and IE, I get this:

```
Producer videos
‹µ—ÑjÛ0†ï÷Caƒ©NWFWHmÖBYae-ewB‘åX,¹’œ.¸·Ú‘-çªó6å&‰$ôÿŸÎ9ò¼UË7Ð}æJ.ã/•å"ËÎó­,„q¹`ÖW¤´RèBíHcMÑrï²å\Öx‘…¯ÙÉìS•›Ê/²³³ÖÆÂ.²YÎò¸£“^¸¼%k•ÏK©ð_T‘5Ûˆ(F1ŠÛ?5›òåU˜ë8wÑÆš3âhuztqŽÏ‚LÚ]+yÅlAŸ¤RÔÕ“}s‡>àZ€ÏÁÂDŠu+Ub`…b^í*Ù$LŠAèy.ã 8X1Ëqã=Q‚ñ OW÷øAuJ´S¢/!4Îè1Î}˜‡Û0'­w2&¦vÆ½äÂ‘ðmt ¨F÷jcš˜+°Ÿ¬]½›ÿQ›ã G{¹W«òÔb¦ÙšÅŸ¼IvbÅ,ÄÖþwmÒñÊÑ?1”dmÅK¨ÜÔ Ó»t(ƒîaºôcpõýbõ—½Xõ^&‚y)¼Ñ]DHh7Ü V‹TeºWÃÎö™„`5,#Ís|)û ƒð™
```

The second link loads just fine in all browsers when requested directly in the browser.

I believe this to be a relatively recent occurrence. And I can't wrap my head around why the behavior is not more consistent across browsers and page loads. Any thoughts?

Comment: I should add I just confirmed the same behavior in Safari on iOS 7.1. First time requesting the page was fine. Hit refresh and encountered what I noted above.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to mention that the included content is generated via Drupal. Just remembered that caching was just enabled and that was the cause. Disabled caching and the issue was resolved.